# How do I create a fake NgForm object in an Angular unit test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a component with a template like the following:

```html
// Template
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(f)">
  <!-- A bunch of form fields -->
</form>
```

My component has a method like:

```ts
onFormSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  this.save();
}
```

I want to write a test that basically looks like this, testing that the save function gets called when the form is submitted:

```ts
it('saves the widget when the form is submitted', () => {
  let testForm = new NgForm([], []);
  testForm.setValue({
    name: "Hello",
    category: "World"
  });
  component.onFormSubmit(testForm);

  // Run tests to check that the component data was updated
  expect(component.data.name).toEqual('Hello');
  expect(component.data.category).toEqual('World');
});
```

How can I create a mock version of the form to pass in to the `onFormSubmit()` function? I have tried doing the above and I get the error: `"There are no form controls registered with this group yet.  If you're using ngModel, you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout)."`

Comment: _onFormSubmit_ doesn't uses *form* parameter. Is your code correct?

Comment: Could you please explain better what's the actual goal of this test? I would test that when the onSubmit function is called, your component actually calls the save() function or even better I would check if the service I'm using actually tried to save the data.

Comment: I've updated the code to clarify what it is doing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should work

```
const testForm = <NgForm>{
    value: {
        name: "Hello",
        category: "World"
    }
};
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? :)

Comment: When I do that, my test says method 'resetForm' does not exist on NgForm object.  How do you mock access to methods of the NgForm object?

Comment: component.loginForm = {form: {}} as NgForm