# Cannot successfully test my NgForm call with Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-ng-form

I am attempting to test whether I can login successfully by sending in username & password inputs through an NgForm, but I cannot seem to get through successfully... Is there something I am missing?

I am currently getting the error:

```
Chrome 67.0.3396 (Mac OS X 10.13.5) LoginComponent should call auth.login when passed a valid form with correct credentials onSubmit FAILED
    Expected spy login to have been called.
        at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/components/login/login.component.spec.ts:87:26)
        at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:288:1)
        at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
```

Comment: What is the output of your test ? And you have your `it` block in your `beforeEach` bloc, you're spying on `logout` to test `login`, and you're not returning an Observable, which will result in an error along the lines of `can't read property 'subscribe' of undefined`.

Comment: Apologies @trichetriche. Updated in question.

Comment: Updated now. Didn't think you'd respond so quickly ;-)

Comment: Well you corrected one issue (which isn't one, it was a request) : what about the others ? returning an observable, spying on the right method ... ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I presumable am spying on the correct thing, I am not so sure whether I am sending the correct json which from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332847/how-do-i-create-a-fake-ngform-object-in-an-angular-unit-test suggests I am...

Comment: 1) your `it` is in your `describe` 2) `onSubmit` calls `service.login`, you spy on `logout` 3) you don't return anything with your spy, you should

Comment: @trichetriche - Balls, bad copy/pasting on my part. I have changed the code to include the `description` properly, and also changed it to be spying on `login`. I will have a look at returning from the spy.

Comment: Okay, now your `onSubmit` function tests `if (form.valid)`, but your mock doesn't contain a `valid` property : `const validFormGoodCreds = <NgForm>{
    value: {
      password: "somePassword",
      username: "someUsername"
    }
  };`. Consider adding it.

Comment: Oh. I assumed that `form.valid` was just a standard feature of the NgForm. I will play and update.

Comment: It indeed is, but if you mock it, you're supposed to provide it !

Comment: So does that mean I would have to provide each and every attribute found in the NgForm as seen in the screenshot at the top?

Comment: Forget that question. @trichetriche you are beautiful! It looks like the problem was me not actually returning anything. Since I don't care what comes back for now, I solved it with a `.and.callthrough()` for now, but I can always do a return for a token value later on. I shall add to the solution.

Comment: Yes and no : the minimal code to provide is the one you use. In your case, since you use valid, you should provide it.

Comment: Well I'm ugly but I know my Angular ;) good job resolving that yourself instead of asking for code solution ! If you have any more issue, feel free to identify me on this question and provide a link to your new one. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came across with much help from @trichetriche was the need for a return on my `spyOn`.

I also needed to add the `valid: true` option to my NgForm json that is to be passed through:

```
const validFormGoodCreds = <NgForm>{
    valid: true,
    value: {
      username: "someUsername",
      password: "somePassword"
    }
  };
```

Since I didn't care about what was returned currently and only want to focus on whether the function is called or not, I opted for the solution of changing the line:

```
authLoginSpy = spyOn(component['authService'], 'login');
```

to

```
authLoginSpy = spyOn(component['authService'], 'login').and.callThrough();
```

This can then see that the function should be run fully and therefore will hit the call to `login()`.

Comment: Although this has resolved your issue, the `valid` property in the mock is also a big part of the solution, maybe you should add that too.

Comment: Good catch. I actually just tested it again myself.